# Spivak Calculus chapter 1 question 14

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Per Spivak:

> Prove that $|a|=|-a|$ (The trick is not to become confused by too many cases. First prove the statement for $a\ge 0$. Why is it then obvious for $a\le0?)$

My proof for  $a\ge0$:
$|a|=a\\|-a| = -(-a)=a$

How exactly would it be obvious for $a\le0$ based on the proof of $a\ge0$? I get that the only thing getting reversed in cases $a\ge0$ and $a\le0$ is their signs, which is nullified by the absolute value function. But I don't know how to write that in a formal proof way.

Comment: If $a \leq 0$ then $-a \geq 0$ and you can apply the already done reasoning to it.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \leq 0$, let $b = - a$. Then $b \geq 0$. Now, because applying $|b| = |-b|$ using your work, we are done. QED